# CSS Transition animation в React.js

Tags: javascript, css-animation, reactjs

Здравствуйте использую React.js. Пишу галерею столкнулся с проблемой. Суть в следующем нужно сделать аналог google photos. При клике на изображение нужно создать копию элемента на том же месте, после чего его увеличить до полноэкранного.

Выделил сам "viewer" в отдельный компонент. Передаю в этот компонент элемент, создаю копию на том же месте в момент инициализации компонента.

По завершению обновляю состояние с меткой mounted для запуска проверки готовности элемента и запуска анимации. Анимации разумеется нет.

Код компонента загрузил на http://pastebin.com/zz2NxvG0

Подскажите каким образом добавить CSS анимацию в компонент для решения задачи.

Если изначально не правильная концепция компонента, прошу показать на примере или объяснить логику действий. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Добавление transition в любой из css блоков эффекта не дает. По видимому из-за смены всего стиля

Comment: не актуально более...